# cx_Oracle version check

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I'm using PyCharm 2019.1 Professional and am able to connect to an Oracle JDBC database using a thin driver `(jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:PORT:SID)`. I'm trying to use the `cx_Oracle` library (version 1.1.9) and `Anaconda 3.6`, but do not seem to have the functions `.connect` or `.makedsn` with the library. I find this unusual, and at a loss.

- Do I just have the wrong `cx_Oracle` version even though I installed using `pip`?
- Is the 1.1.9 version that works with `Anaconda 3.6` just not have these functions?
- Or is there a different/easier library I can use to connect with `jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:PORT:SID`?

```py
dir(cx_Oracle)
```

Outputs:

> ['ARRAY',  'BIGINT',  'BINARY',  'BLANK_SCHEMA',  'BLOB',  'BOOLEAN',
> 'BigInteger',  'Binary',  'Boolean',  'CHAR',  'CLOB',
> 'CheckConstraint',  'Column',  'ColumnDefault',  'Constraint',
> 'DATE',  'DATETIME',  'DDL',  'DECIMAL',  'Date',  'DateTime',
> 'DefaultClause',  'Enum',  'FLOAT',  'FetchedValue',  'Float',
> 'ForeignKey',  'ForeignKeyConstraint',  'INT',  'INTEGER',  'Index',
> 'Integer',  'Interval',  'JSON',  'LargeBinary',  'MetaData',
> 'NCHAR',  'NUMERIC',  'NVARCHAR',  'Numeric',  'PassiveDefault',
> 'PickleType',  'PrimaryKeyConstraint',  'REAL',  'SMALLINT',
> 'Sequence',  'SmallInteger',  'String',  'TEXT',  'TIME',
> 'TIMESTAMP',  'Table',  'Text',  'ThreadLocalMetaData',  'Time',
> 'TypeDecorator',  'Unicode',  'UnicodeText',  'UniqueConstraint',
> 'VARBINARY',  'VARCHAR',  '**all**',  '**builtins**',  '**cached**',
> '**doc**',  '**file**',  '**go',  '**loader**',  '**name**',
> '**package**',  '**path**',  '**spec**',  '**version**',  'alias',
> 'all*',  'and*',  'any_',  'asc',  'between',  'bindparam',  'case',
> 'cast',  'collate',  'column',  'create_engine',  'delete',  'desc',
> 'distinct',  'engine',  'engine_from_config',  'event',  'events',
> 'exc',  'except_',  'except_all',  'exists',  'extract',  'false',
> 'func',  'funcfilter',  'insert',  'inspect',  'inspection',
> 'interfaces',  'intersect',  'intersect_all',  'join',  'lateral',
> 'literal',  'literal_column',  'log',  'modifier',  'not_',  'null',
> 'or_',  'outerjoin',  'outparam',  'over',  'pool',  'processors',
> 'schema',  'select',  'sql',  'subquery',  'table',  'tablesample',
> 'text',  'true',  'tuple_',  'type_coerce',  'types',  'union',
> 'union_all',  'update',  'util',  'within_group']

Answer (score 3):

To check the version of cx_Oracle

1. You must have python
2. Use your python shell, command prompt, or your code/text editor
3. Print out the following code

```
C:\Users>python
Python 3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle
>>> print(cx_Oracle.version)
8.3.0
>>> exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Print out the value of `cx_Oracle.version`. The version number 1.1.9 is not a valid cx_Oracle version! The latest version is 7.2.1 and has a much different set of values than the ones you printed! Take a look at the [cx_Oracle installation documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) and the [top level module cx_Oracle documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html) to get an idea of what I am talking about. If you have further questions, adjust your question above and add a comment below and I'll see if I can help further.